# Android file manager similar to Solid explorer

Tags: android, file-management

I'm looking for a file manager with the following requirements:

1. Dark theme
2. Multiple tabs/panes
3. Multimedia support - built in image viewer at least. Thumbnail generation too.
4. SMB support
5. Bookmarks
6. Per-folder sort
7. **Sort by last modified date**

The last one is important, because solid explorer covers all these criteria, except its "date" sort is by last accessed date, which makes it useless - every time you access a file, the order changes. And the developer is unresponsive so that's not changing.

Both free and paid apps are fine.

Answer (score -1):

Check out FX Explorer https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.fx
It meets all your requirements. (Some are paid features.) I'm using it for the past few years and love it.

Comment: The sorting and the image viewer are broken however. _Technically_ they are present, however both these features are unusable in their current state.

Comment: @martixy They both work perfectly fine for me. Perhaps it is only a paid feature. What is the issue?

Comment: More than half the time, when I try to swipe in the image viewer, it won't change. And you cannot sort a single folder, without first sorting EVERYTHING. Makes for a *miserable* user experience.

Comment: @martixy not sure about the image viewer. It works perfectly on my device. I can swipe away and it works. Regarding sorting, there is a save option which allows you to save different sort criteria per folder.

Comment: And you cannot sort a single folder, without first sorting EVERYTHING.